# java.lang.AssertionError: CALL 'public final fun <get-currentComposer>

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to make a project using jetPack Compose , i have all necessary dependencies for it to work but when i run my app , it throws an error that i couldn't find a solution for

- This is the error :

```
 java.lang.AssertionError: CALL 'public final fun <get-currentComposer> (): androidx.compose.runtime.Composer<*> declared in androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt' type=androidx.compose.runtime.Composer<*> origin=FOR_LOOP_ITERATOR
```

- All dependencies that i added

```
 def jetpackDef = "1.0.0-alpha09"


  // Jetpack compose navigation
        implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha04"

implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$jetpackDef"
        // Tooling support (Previews, etc.)
        implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$jetpackDef"
        // Foundation (Border, Background, Box, Image, Scroll, shapes, animations, etc.)
        implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$jetpackDef"
        // Material Design
        implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$jetpackDef"
        // Material design icons
        implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:$jetpackDef"
        implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$jetpackDef"
        // Integration with observables
        implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$jetpackDef"
        implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-rxjava2:$jetpackDef"
        implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:$jetpackDef"


     buildFeatures {
        // Enables Jetpack Compose for this module
        compose true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        useIR = true
    }
```

Any Help would be appreciated guys , thank you .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got it working by settings the composeOptions, I got this error when I had kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.0.0-alpha08", whilst rest of the libraries where alpha09.

```
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerVersion = "1.4.21"
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.0.0-alpha09"
    }
```

Comment: Oh, made the same mistake. I was having alpha08 in composeOptions but all the compose dependencies I was using were on alpha09.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with compose version `alpha09`, downgrade to `alpha08` and it should work.

Source:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176046527

Comment: Thank you for the answer i switched even composeOptions to alpha 09 and it workd fine now , thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

For me JuliusScrip's answer didn't completely solve it: if you use `ext.kotlin_version` in your `build.gradle(:project)` file, you'll need to update that too:

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.21"
  ...
}
```

For anyone needing more details, this video is completely about this error: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=itvv6m4haGY&feature=emb_logo