# Couldn't inline method call 'Column' into local final fun <anonymous>() in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I was starting a simple base project in jetpack compose using **Android studio 2020.3.1 Canary 15**. I followed this guide https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup & added needed dependencies also I updated them to latest `beta06` because it was showing a warning.

Now, I have following error when I run:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Couldn't inline method call 'Column' into
local final fun <anonymous>(): kotlin.Unit defined in <packagename>.onCreate
{
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {

            }
        }
Cause: Not generated
```

My project level `build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha15"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.32"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My app level `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.<packagename>"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.0.0-beta06"
    }
}

tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.0-beta06'
    // Tooling support (Previews, etc.)
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-beta06'
    // Foundation (Border, Background, Box, Image, Scroll, shapes, animations, etc.)
    implementation 'androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.0.0-beta06'
    // Material Design
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.0-beta06'
    // Material design icons
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:1.0.0-beta06'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.0.0-beta06'
    // Integration with activities
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha07'
    // Integration with ViewModels
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha04'
    // Integration with observables
    implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.0.0-beta06'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-rxjava2:1.0.0-beta06'
}
```

My `MainActivity` code where error is occuring:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material.CircularProgressIndicator
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have already tried this: [java.lang.AssertionError: CALL 'public final fun <get-currentComposer>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65462221/java-lang-assertionerror-call-public-final-fun-get-currentcomposer)

Also such other answers but none work for me.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: alpha15 is pretty old. Have you tried upgrading to beta07? If this still reproduces consider reporting it as a bug so it can be tracked and fixed.

Comment: @chuckj It says `Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-beta07` followed by some long URLs. is this what you wanted me to update?

Comment: I misread this. You are using `beta06`. `beta07` was just release and might address this. If it doesn't please submit a bug so this can be tracked and fixed.

Comment: @chuckj Noted. I'll try it

Answer (score 35, accepted):

please try to add this in the app-level build.gradle file inside the android block

```
buildFeatures {
        compose true
}
```